# How to perform UI actions from Socket.io On Function

Tags: ios, swift, sockets

I am new to using socket.io. I have made a singleton class for socket works and I am using an Instance of it in my app.

My question is: How to perform any action after receiving the data in the `On` function when I am on a different view controller?

```
import Foundation
import SocketIO
import UIKit

protocol testUI {

    func fareUpdate(amount:NSNumber)


}

var delegate:testUI?

class SocketHelper {

    static let shared = SocketHelper()
    var socket: SocketIOClient!

    let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "http://13.59.81.136:3355/")!, config: [.log(true), .compress, .connectParams(["token":user.shared.token])] )

    private init() {
        socket = manager.defaultSocket
    }

    func connectSocket(completion: @escaping(Bool) -> () ) {
        disconnectSocket()
//        socket.on(clientEvent: .connect) {[weak self] (data, ack) in
//            print("socket connected")
//            self?.socket.removeAllHandlers()
//            completion(true)
//        }
        socket.connect()
    }

    func disconnectSocket() {
        socket.removeAllHandlers()
        socket.disconnect()
        print("socket Disconnected")
    }

    func testStatus(){
        print(socket.status)
    }

    func checkConnection() -> Bool {
        if socket.manager?.status == .connected {
            return true
        }
        return false

    }

    enum Events {

        case search

        func getFareEstimate(params:NSDictionary){
            SocketHelper.shared.socket.emit("fareEstimate" , params)

        }

        func listen(completion: @escaping (Any) -> Void) {


            SocketHelper.shared.socket!.on("rideFares") { (response, emitter) in

                print(response)

                let dic = response as! NSArray

                let data = dic[0] as! NSDictionary

                let fare = data["fare"] as! NSNumber

                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    delegate?.fareUpdate(amount: fare)

                }


            }



//        func off() {
//            SocketHelper.shared.socket.off(listnerName)
//        }

    }

}
}
```

I have tried using a delegate but it doesn't seem to work. I could be on multiple view controllers when the socket receives the data in the `On` function.

Comment: did you try `NotificationCenter` ?

Comment: how will that work?